# pgAdmin4 container deployment: add multiple pgAdmin users

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4, user-management

I have a containerized setup of pgAdmin4 V6.2 in server mode running. As described in the [documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html) I supplied the `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL` and `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD` environment variables in order to create a default user.

I know I can add more pgAdmin users (NOT database users!) in the [user management dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/user_management.html). However, I would like to add multiple users on deployment, just like the default user. Is that possible in any way so in order to integrate this step in my CI pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to import users currently in pgAdmin.
However, you can mount your own storage directory - https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.3/container_deployment.html#mapped-files-and-directories which will persist even if docker is restarted. You just need to create the users once.

Comment: Just what I thought. Thank you for your answer @AdityaToshniwal, I'll try it with a persistant volume then.